# Разобрать строку, в которой могут встречаться различные записи

Tags: строки, переменные, php, функции

Добрый день.

Есть запись:

```
$str = 'Тут могут быть слова и цифры разные. Записи цифр и букв могут идти вместе. Например: М20, js80000b';
```

Нужно вывести строку без изменений, но выделить тегом `<b>слово</b>`, все слова в которых не менее трех символов. Цифры выделяем жирным с любым кол-вом знаков.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Тут могут быть слова и цифры разные. Записи цифр и букв могут идти вместе. Например: М20, js80000b 2 13 34dsd sd s bgbg s4';
echo preg_replace('/(?<= |^)([\d\w]{3,}|[\d]+)(?= |,|\.|:|$)/iu','<b>\1</b>',$str);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но чет не получилось)

Comment: preg_replace('/( |,|\.)([\d\wабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфчхцшщъьыэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЧЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦШЩЬЪЫЭЮЯ]{3,}|[\d]+)( |,|\.)/','\1<b>\2</b>\3',$str);

так лучше?

Comment: Может, я что-то напутал? ) Так делаю:

    $str = 'Тут могут быть слова и цифры разные. Записи цифр и букв могут идти вместе. Например: М20, js80000b';
    preg_replace('/ ([\d\w]{3,}|[\d]+) /',' <b>\1</b> ',$str);
    echo $str;

Верно?

Comment: ну,во первых echo preg_replace( .. ); или $str=preg_repalce( ... ); echo $str;
во-вторых \w почему-то кириллицу за символ не считает,попробуйте мой последний вариант.

Comment: http://www.php.su/lessons/?lesson_17
Вот мануал.

    echo preg_replace('/( |,|\.)([\d\wа-яё]{3,}|[\d]+)(?= |,|\.|:)/iu','\1<b>\2</b>',$str);

Вот я немного улучшил регулярку.

Дальше попробуйте сами разобраться.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать)

Comment: поставьте юникодный флаг и забудьте про строкопроблемы

Comment: Etki, да я слабо в php разбираюсь) Был бы рад готовому примеру)

Comment: Я ответ свой переписал,там готовое решение